# Assign multiple values from a list, by oder ,for multiple rows in dataframe

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

To be simple , I have a list abc , with `abc=[a,b,c,d,e]`.

I want to assign these values for column 'Text'in the dataframe DF that have value in column 'Number' = 2. I know that the dataframe have 5 rows that meet this condition, for eg row 1, 2,3 ,4 5. What I want is Value in row1 =a, row2 =b , row3=c, row4 =d ,row5=e
I write the code like that:

```
 i=0
 for row1 in range(0,len(df)):
     if  df.iloc[row1]['Number']==2:
        df.set_value(df.index[row1], 'Text',abc[i])
        i=i+1
```

But what I receive are value in row 1,2,3,4 5 get the same value e .
Could you guys please give me the way to do it. Thank you very much

Comment: One more thing that I want to add is that  at first my column Text contains Nan value

Answer (score 1):

Without modifying too much of your code, I was able to use the [enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) function instead of your `i` loop. I am using Python 3.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
# create sample dataframe
abc = ['a','b','c','d','e', 'f']
data = {'Text':['foo', 'bar', 'spam', 'eggs', 'ham', 'asdf'],
        'Number':[2, 2, 5, 2, 2, 3]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data) 
df = df[['Text', 'Number']] # reordering df
print(df)

# Original question code:
# i=0
# for row1 in range(0,len(df)):
#     if df.iloc[row1]['Number']==2:
#         df.set_value(df.index[row1], 'Text',abc[i])
#         i=i+1

# Pseudocode: 
# if row value for the column 'number' is 2:
#     set the value for the column 'text' at an index to the value for abc[index]
for idx, row1 in enumerate(range(0, len(df))):
    if df.iloc[row1]['Number'] == 2:
        df.set_value(df.index[row1], 'Text', abc[idx])
print(df)
```

Please note that set_value is depreciated and will be removed in a future release.

Results:

```
    text  number
0     a       2
1     b       2
2  spam       5
3     d       2
4     e       2
5  asdf       3

FutureWarning: set_value is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use .at[] or .iat[] accessors instead
```

Comment: I got this error when I apply your code IndexError: list index out of range.The problem is that my DF have , for eg , 1000 rows and just 5 rows with value in column Number=2 . So i think we can use enumerate() here

Comment: @Rive11 I have updated my answer to fix any typos. You should be able to copy, paste, and run my entire code in a new .py file without any errors. The error you received may be because your existing DF has more rows than the length of List abc - this means the for loop is trying to access an index greater than the number of elements in List abc. In this case, you can replace `enumerate(range(0, len(df)))` with `enumerate(range(0, len(abc)))` which only checks the rows up to index `len(abc)-1`

Comment: follwing your example, I keep the list abc( with 6 elements) and created a new df with 9 rows , in which they have 6 rows that the number in column text =2.
      data = {'Text':['foo', 'bar', 'spam', 'eggs', 'ham', 'asdf','cvddd','vfhfhhfhf','cgddd','aa'],
        'Number':[2, 2, 5, 2, 4,2, 3,2,4,2]}  . I modify your code with enumerate(range(0, len(abc))) .In the result,  the element 'c' and 'e' in list abc are removed and two last '2' in df are still not replaced by the element in abc So do you know how to fix this problem?Thank you very much

Comment: If you want to replace the value for (up to) every row in the df, the list abc and your df have to be the same length. If you look at the for loop, using `range(0, len(abc))` will only iterate through the df up to the length of the list abc. If your dataframe is longer than your list, the loop will not replace any rows past the row with index equal to the length of the list.

Comment: Yes .This Is the problem .But I have to work with the df with much more rows than the length of list. So do you know other way that I can do to deal with my case . I try to create the new list  B that contains the positions of rows having the value in Number =2.   B=[0, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9]  .Is there any way that I can do with two lists ?

Comment: Yes, you can use the second list to decide what indices to replace, but that is not useful if you have to manually enter each index in that list. This new request is now different than your original question. For clarification, what values do you plan to place in the df past the length of your list? Are you trying to repeat elements in the list abc for 2's farther down in the df?